# Mortage Calc - formulas questions

Tags: javascript, calculator

I'm working with a loan calculator that was built for me. I'm using it as a way to learn a bit of js.

Can somone explain to me what formula these lines of code are performing?

```
//feed datatable
const datatable = $('#mortgageTable').DataTable({
    dom: 'ftip',
    data: breakdown(),
    columns: [
        {data: 'month', type: 'mmmyyyy', title: 'Month', render: (data, type, row, meta) => monthNames[meta.row%12]+', '+parseFloat(parseFloat($('#year').val())+Math.floor(meta.row/12))},
        {data: 'principal', title: 'Principal', render: () => ($('#amount').val()/$('#term').val()).toFixed(2)},
        {data: 'interest', title: 'Monthly Interest', render: (data, type, row, meta) => ($('#amount').val()*(1-meta.row/$('#term').val())*$('#interest').val()/1200).toFixed(2)},
        {data: 'aninterest', title: 'Annual Interest', render: (data, type, row, meta) => ($('#amount').val()*(1-meta.row/$('#term').val())*$('#interest').val()/100).toFixed(2)},
        {data: 'balance', title: 'Balance', render: (data, type, row, meta) => ($('#amount').val()*(1-meta.row/$('#term').val())).toFixed(2)}
    ]
});
```

I apologize in advance if I've left out important information. I didn't include the whole program in order to keep the post short. Can include it if it would help.

Comment: Are you asking about the `render` functions, what `DataTable({...})` is doing, or something else? It's a little confusing what exactly you are asking about and what you don't understand about it.

Comment: Sorry for my lack of specificity. I'm trying to figure out how to read the formulas.
for example: in the Monthly Interest line, i'm assuming #amount isn't tied to any variable? where #term and #interest are defined in the begging of each data line?

Trying to understand how the formulas are written so for exmaple:
 the line that begins "{data: 'interest' " is it saying amount * term * interest /1200?

I hope i'm being clear, i don't know terminology etc.

Comment: The calls like `$('#amount').val()` are jQuery selectors that find an element by it's `id` attribute and then attempt to evaluate it's `value`. So each of those functions is evaluating those values into a number (really a string, since `.toFixed()` returns a string representation of a number with two digits after the period.

Comment: Ah I see.. # being the symbol for Id in html cool.. 
and so this string:
($('#amount').val()*(1-meta.row/$('#term').val())
says "id amount value * id term - essentially multiplying amount by term? I think i'm getting it.

Comment: it would be more like: `amount * (1 - meta.row / term)`. The result of that (say a number, like 100) would then be changed to "100.00" for display.